# Character encoding problem when move between PCs

Tags: craft3, database, mamp

I'm using MAMP PRO to develop site in local environment with Cloud functions for sync.
Everything works fine except for character coding of entries' text. Evidently a problem with encoding but I can't find the cause.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: This needs more information … what issues are you seeing? In what context? What are you expecting to see?

Comment: Sure! The issues are about text, in particular with accented characters. First I have wrote this entry in my PC. Than using MAMP PRO Cloud I sync Craft project (files and db) on another PC, where the text encoding messed-up!  For example: _affidabilità_ on first PC is saved as _affidabilitÃ_ on second.